# Is there overloaded sqrt etc math functions

Tags: c++

I am working on some c++ code and use math.h library. Since Math library is for C, so for example, sqrt function has many different names like sqrt, sqrtf, sqrtl, I am wondering if there is a c++ one which has only one name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, see `std::sqrt` in header [`<cmath>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt).

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1xa99e6.aspx  explains the difference .
In C++  `sqrt()` accepts either a `double`, a `float` or a `long double` while `sqrtf()` accepts only a float.
The only reason why there's two different versions is because C did not support overloading, so there had to be two functions.
`C++` allows overloading, so there are actually three different versions of `sqrt()` taking floating point arguments of various sizes.
In `C++`, the overloaded `sqrt` (defined in `cmath`, in `namespace std`) should be used.